# No such file or directory gmapping.launch.xml or amcl.launch.xml under turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/

Tags: ros, amcl-demo.launch, turtlebot-navigation, turtlebot-gazebo, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting the following error

```
while processing /opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/amcl.launch.xml: Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/amcl.launch.xml' The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

While running command

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo amcl_demo.launch
```

This command was working fine before, two weeks back,  Is there update occurred to the package, cause the file to be missing or file location changed !

I tried  to reinstall ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-pkg and turtlebot navigation package, but still the same error, and the file amcl.launch.xml not there under `/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/`

EDITED:

The amcl_demo.launch contains

```
<include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/amcl.launch.xml">
```

I noticed that latest changes to turtlebot_nvaigation package on  2.3.7 (2016-11-01)

contains the change

> Merge pull request #152 from
> kevincwells/r200
>
> Parameterize AMCL and GMapping launch
> files for individual cameras.

Changes log for the package  at
https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/blob/indigo/turtlebot_navigation/CHANGELOG.rst

File locations changed in turtlebot_navigation:

...avigation/launch/includes/amcl.launch.xml → ...tion/launch/includes/amcl/amcl.launch.xml

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249568/no-such-file-or-directory-gmapping.launch.xml-or-amcl.launch.xml-under-turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes//) by [MZAIADY](https://answers.ros.org/users/28690/mzaiady/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2016-12-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved (Work around until turtlebot_gazebo get updates) by  updating the

```
sudo gedit  /opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/launch/amcl_demo.launch
```

To the following (same logic included in the updated  turtlebot_navigation/launch/amcl_demo.launch ),

```
    <launch>
  <!-- Map server -->
  <arg name="map_file" default="$(env TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_MAP_FILE)"/>
  <arg name="3d_sensor" default="$(env TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR)"/>  <!-- r200, kinect, asus_xtion_pro -->

  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />

  <!-- Localization -->
  <arg name="initial_pose_x" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_y" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_a" default="0.0"/>
 <arg name="custom_amcl_launch_file" default="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/amcl/$(arg 3d_sensor)_amcl.launch.xml"/> 

  <include file="$(arg custom_amcl_launch_file)">
    <arg name="initial_pose_x" value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_y" value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_a" value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- Move base -->
 <arg name="custom_param_file" default="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/$(arg 3d_sensor)_costmap_params.yaml"/>*
 <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/move_base.launch.xml">
 <arg name="custom_param_file" value="$(arg custom_param_file)"/>
 </include>
</launch>
```

Replaced

```
<include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/amcl.launch.xml">
```

With:

```
<arg name="3d_sensor" default="$(env TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR)"/> 
<arg name="custom_amcl_launch_file" default="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/amcl/$(arg 3d_sensor)_amcl.launch.xml"/> 
  <include file="$(arg custom_amcl_launch_file)">
```

The issue also if you creating a new map, so to make my answer complete, also gmapping-demo.launch need to be updated:

```
 sudo gedit /opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/launch/gmapping_demo.launch
```

and replace the content with :

```
<launch>
  <arg name="3d_sensor" default="$(env TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR)"/>  <!-- r200, kinect, asus_xtion_pro -->
  <arg name="custom_gmapping_launch_file" default="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/gmapping/$(arg 3d_sensor)_gmapping.launch.xml"/>
  <include file="$(arg custom_gmapping_launch_file)"/>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [MZAIADY](https://answers.ros.org/users/28690/mzaiady/) with karma: 38 on 2016-12-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem with: `/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/launch/gmapping_demo.launch`

problem fixed with changing the path and added the folder gmapping to the path (`/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/gmapping/gmapping_demo.launch`) with using

```
sudo gedit /opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/launch/gmapping_demo.launch
```

I don't know why the path is wrong.

thanks,

Erik4

---

Originally posted by [Erik4](https://answers.ros.org/users/29019/erik4/) with karma: 31 on 2017-01-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3